# How do I create/populate a sheet within an ods file without destroying the other sheets in the file?

Tags: python, csv, pyexcel

My python code works in taking data from a .csv file and converting and saving it to a .ods file.  The problem is when it saves to the new file it deletes the other sheets within the file it saves to.  How do I get it to update the new file without deleting the other sheets?

```
import csv, shutil, os, glob
from pyexcel_ods3 import save_data
from collections import OrderedDict

# finds the latest file from my downloads folder
newest = max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)

my_file = open(newest)
file_reader = csv.reader(my_file)
file_data = list(file_reader)

# identifies the data structure
file_header = ['Details', 'Posting Date', 'Description', 'Amount', 'Type', 'Balance', 'Check or Slip #']

# compares the data structure in the csv file to the one used for this script
if file_data[0] == file_header:
    del file_data[0] # removes the header form the csv file
    date = file_data[0][1]
    f_date = date.split('/')
    f_date_formatted = '{}-{}-{}'.format(f_date[2], f_date[0], f_date[1])
    for i in file_data: # organizes the data
        i[4] = ''
        transaction = float(i[3])
        if transaction > 0:
            i[3] = ''
            i[4] = transaction
    my_file.close()

    # creates a copy of the unpopulated file.  This file has 3 existing sheets.  One sheet is called 'DATA'
    shutil.copy('Checkbook Monthly balance.ods', 'Checkbook Monthly balance thru {}.ods'.format(f_date_formatted))

    # populates the sheet called 'DATA'
    data = OrderedDict()
    data.update({'DATA': file_data})
    save_data('Checkbook Monthly balance thru {}.ods'.format(f_date_formatted), data)

else:
    print('It appears the bank changed the table format.  Check the .csv file for a difference in the data structure.')
    my_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the old file has been over written, previous data was wiped out.

In order to preserve the existing data, you need to read the data back via '[get_data(..)](http://pyexcel-io.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyexcel_io.get_data.html)', then append content, and save all of them back.

Comment: I appreciate your reply.  I'm pretty new to Python and am struggling with how to format this.  I understand what you are saying though.  I just need help with the format.

Comment: get_data('Checkbook Monthly balance.ods') will return a dictionary: {'DATA': file_data} too.

Comment: ok. I was able to do what I want and keep the other sheets, however it removes all of the formatting from the other sheets.  Any way to keep the formatting?

Comment: My apologies. I thought you would use the ods sheet produced by save_data(..). I am afraid that pyexcel would not pay attention to formatting and that's why the formatting is lost.

Comment: No apologies necessary.  Thank you for your help.  I may have to start converting the .ods files to .xls as I believe there is more options when dealing with .xls.

Comment: You may consider xlrd and xlutils. Please visit http://www.python-excel.org/ for more info.